# w qualifer not working as expected (not using expected layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, screen-resolution

I have been creating some tests today to check how w qualifier works in android. My idea was that I wanted different layouts for smaller or equal to 320dp, smaller or equal to 480dp, and smaller or equal to 720dp screens. I have this 3 folders in eclipse (layout-320dp, layout-w480-dp and layout-w720dp). The problem is that when I previsualize the layouts with differnt screen configurations I see android not using the expected layout. Some examples:

1. Nexus One with 480x800 should take layout in w480 but it takes the one in w320
2. Nexus S with same resolution does same thing
3. Nexus 7 with 800x1280 should take layout in w720 but it takes the one in w480

Could anybody guess what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you need to use `layout-sw720dp` etc etc, going by screen width.

I assume you have calculated the correct pixel to dp for these screens. For exmaple, I have a Nexus 7 and I know it takes drawables and layouts from `layout-sw600dp` not 720dp. 720dp is for 10 inch screens. Work from screen width. Your error here is picking the wrong folder.

Of course look here too because it is packed with information, it will provide everything you need:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: w is a valid configuration qualifer too. It refers only to the width. sw qualifier referes to the minimum size between width and height. I think my problem could be as you say thinking than a resolution of 1 pixel matches 1 dp which obviously is wrong. I must work out the resolution to dpis correctly. Must check it.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm used to sw which is why I mentioned it. 1 pixel is definitely not 1dp like you say so that is probably where you error is. There are a few converters out there such as this: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/